# Adding features to Clipboard ActionBar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my app, I want to be able to start my own function when user copy a text to the clipboard.

I'm overriding function onActionModeFinished and as I want to be sure user tapped on Copy I'm getting selected navigation index. Unfortunately if always return -1. Is there something I'm doing wrong here ?

```
@Override
public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeFinished(mode);

    if (_actionBar != null) {
        int index = _actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex();
        // here index is always -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBar can contain tabs and list selector on the left side. So, getSelectedNavigationIndex is used to get the position in this navigation items not in the menu items located in the right side.